# Schema markup error in Google Webmaster Tools: Missing required field "name (fn)"

Tags: google-search-console, microdata, markup

I'm receiving this schema markup error when I try to validate my code in Google Webmaster Tools:

> Error: Missing required field "name (fn)".

I'm trying to markup the following:

- Type: Schema product
- Property: Image

This is my domain: www(dot)wishpicker(dot)com

Comment: Please include a (minimal) code example in your question.

Comment: There are no errors in the rich snippet testing tool as you can see [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=www.wishpicker.com). Specifically where and what are you trying to validate?

Comment: the error is on the product pages eg. http://www(dot)wishpicker(dot)com/giftproducts/Blackforest-Cake-BFC1/d9409zz9my

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en&ref_topic=1088474)  describes what Google is expecting in terms of a product listing, items in bold are required.

So from looking at your mark-up you have the name property of product in the wrong place as it comes after the image property, I would move this above the image and I think it should validate OK.

```
<span itemprop="name">Blackforest Cake BFC1 </span>
```